# How to choose an iOS provisioning profile command line while using Qmake to build

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, provisioning-profile, qmake

I am building my `QtApp` command line for `iOS` with `qmake` command like so:

```
qmake MyApp.pro -spec macx-ios-clang CONFIG+=iphoneos CONFIG+=device CONFIG+=$release
```

But I am getting a **code signing error** after compilation succeeds:

```
MyApp requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
```

The signing works if I choose the required provisioning profile from Xcode UI but I need to do this command line using `Qmake`.

**How can I choose a provisioning profile command line with qmake command ?**

**PS:** *I have multiple provisioning profiles in Xcode. This is possibly happening due to this?*

Comment: `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="${TEAM_ID}" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${SIGNING_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROFILE_UUID}"` is what I do via CommandLine for xcodebuild.

Comment: @Brandon **you mean the full command like this ?** - `qmake MyApp.pro -spec macx-ios-clang CONFIG+=iphoneos CONFIG+=device CONFIG+=$release DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="${TEAM_ID}" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${SIGNING_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROFILE_UUID}`

Comment: @Brandon not sure if the same will work with `Qmake`. can give a try

Comment: For QMake, according to QTBug, you can use: `QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM, QMAKE_XCODE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY,  QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE`: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38782

Comment: I somehow need to use `QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE` with the `qmake` command to pick up the correct provisioning profile. Not sure how

Comment: I am able to build the App from Xcode. I want to set `QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE ` & `QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` in my app's .pro file. How can I know from Xcode as to what values to set for `QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE ` & `QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` ?

Comment: `QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE=` the UUID of the provisioning profile that you get when you press other in XCode or view the profile in finder as a text file, it'll have a UUID embedded in it. As for `QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=` the TeamID from the developer portal (Go to AppleDeveloper website, after you sign in and check the URL. Otherwise choose certificates and check the URL again). If it isn't in the URL, check XCode for the TeamID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148971/discussion-between-hal9000-kernel-and-brandon).