# How can I sign my Qt App command line to deploy it on iOS AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, qmake, ios-provisioning

I trying to sign my `QtApp` with `Xcode 8.3.3` & `Qt 5.7` for `iOS` from command line by running `Qmake` as I need to do it for my jenkins build environment.

As I found from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039025/how-to-choose-an-ios-provisioning-profile-command-line-while-using-qmake-to-buil?noredirect=1#comment77059933_45039025), I am manually mentioning the following in project or `MyApp.pro` file.

```
QMAKE_XCODE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY
QMAKE_PROVISIONING_PROFILE
QMAKE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM
```

But then it complains the following asking me to manually switch it from project editor ?

> MyApp has conflicting provisioning settings. MyApp is automatically
>   signed, but provisioning profile xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx has been manually
>   specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the
>   build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project
>   editor. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 10.3'

I am well able to sign & run it from Xcode UI editor but I need to do it from command line. **How can I sign my app for iOS command line ?**

So I tried to run `xcodebuild` on the `MyApp.xcodeproj` that was generated from `qmake` with the below command:

```
xcodebuild -project "MyApp.xcodeproj" -target "MyApp" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Company Name (XXXXXXXXX)"
```

But I got the same error again:

> MyApp has conflicting provisioning settings. MyApp is automatically
>   signed, but provisioning profile xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx has been manually
>   specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the
>   build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project
>   editor. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 10.3'

Else: **If I want to sign a `.xcodeproj` from command line, then how should I configure code signing certificates and provisioning profiles to build to an iOS device ?**

**Figured during investigation that:**
I can run the command as

```
xcodebuild -project "MyApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "MyApp" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration Release
```

to sign **but** before that I need to open `MyApp.xcodeproj` in `Xcode` & select `Automatically Manage Signing` on `Xcode` UI to do that ? *Isn't there some way set Xcode to always remember the `Automatically Manage Signing` with the required provisioning profile ?* **If this is answered by some of you experts out there then the whole problem is solved**